# AttributeError: module 'collections' has no attribute 'Iterable'

Tags: python, pdf, attributeerror, pdftables

I am using the "pdftables" library to extract tables from a pdf.

This is my code:

```
import pdftables

pg = pdftables.get_pdf_page(open("filename.pdf","rb"),253)

print(pg)

table = pdftables.page_to_tables(pg)

print(table)
```

I am getting this error and I am not sure what's causing it.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\gayak\OneDrive\Documents\PDF to Database\PDF_to_Tables_3.py", line 9, in <module>
    table = pdftables.page_to_tables(pg)
  File "C:\Users\gayak\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pdftables\pdftables.py", line 485, in page_to_tables
    box_list = LeafList().populate(page, flt).purge_empty_text()
  File "C:\Users\gayak\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pdftables\tree.py", line 98, in populate
    for obj in children(pdfpage):
  File "C:\Users\gayak\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pdftables\tree.py", line 75, in children
    if isinstance(obj, collections.Iterable):
AttributeError: module 'collections' has no attribute 'Iterable'
```

The version of python I am using is python 3.10.4

I used `pip install pdftables.six` to get the library

Comment: Change `if isinstance(obj, collections.Iterable):` to `if isinstance(obj, collections.abc.Iterable):` in this `C:\Users\gayak\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pdftables\tree.py` file.

Answer (score 8):

If you don't want to change the source code, there is an easier way. Just use this in your script after importing.

```
import collections
collections.Iterable = collections.abc.Iterable
```

Answer (score 0):

As the Error says, the attribute isn't valid. When using `collection.Iterable` then it not finds the `Iterable` attribute. This can have different reasons but in this case, after looking on the package files on Github, i noticed that you are missing the abc keyword. I not tried this solution, but I'm 95% sure that using `collections.abc.Iterable` will do the thing.

Answer (score 0):

```py
import collections 
from _collections_abc import Iterable 
collection.Iterable = Iterable
```

**This should work**

Comment: `_collections_abc` is not part of the public API, so depending on it is a bad idea.

Answer (score -1):

A simple fix that works for python3.10:

Under directory
**/usr/lib/python3.10/collections/__ init__.py**

**Note**: The path might change depending

Add this line of code:

`from _collections_abc import Iterable`